# Characters missing when embedding PDF with pdftex

Tags: fonts, graphics, errors, pdftex

I have the feeling this must have been asked before, but I couldn't find it with search...

When I run the following test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% \pdfmapfile{+rotis.map}

% \renewcommand\rmdefault{rotissemisans}
% \renewcommand\seriesdefault{l}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

MF

foo bar

\bigskip

\noindent\fbox{\includegraphics{12462}}

\end{document}
```

through pdflatex with this PDF file http://www.quinscape.de/download/examples/12462.pdf then I receive the following, expected result:

[image: correct result]

But when I uncomment the three lines configuring Rotis Semi Sans Light as the document font, I unexpectedly get:

[image]

That is, a lot of characters are missing from the embedded PDF file. I can deduce this has something to do with the fact that the font embedded in the embedded PDF is the same as the document font, combined with font subsetting, but what exactly has gone wrong, and what are my options?

Please excuse that I can't upload the complete font setup. The generated PDF is here: http://www.quinscape.de/download/examples/test.pdf (more precisely, an older version without the nice frame, but with the same error).

Here's the relevant line from the map file:

```
pr3l8r  RotisSemiSans-Light " TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <pr3l8a.pfb
```

Maybe some expert can analyse something or has seen this before?

**Update**: When I add the line

```
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts 1
```

to the preamble, then I get

[image]

which looks Ok, though it does not really relate to what the documentation says this switch does :-)

Here's the relevant part from the pdftex manual, but I can't comprehend the connection to the case at hand:

> `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts` *(integer)*
>
> If positive, this parameter forces
>   pdfTeX to include fonts from a pdf file loaded with `\pdfximage`, even
>   if those fonts are available on disk. Bigger files might be created,
>   but included pdf files are sure to be embedded with the adequate
>   fonts; indeed, the fonts on disk might be different from the embedded
>   ones, and glyphs might be missing.

My remaining problem now is that I am generating documents which can contain literally thousands of these embedded diagrams, and I fear that if all the embedded fonts are copied to the document PDF, it might get huge or otherwise too unwieldy for prepress tools...

Comment: What happens if you don't uncomment the line changing the series default but only the other lines?

Comment: @cfr  In that case the light font is not used in the main text and thus the result of embedding is the same as for cmr (i.e., Ok).

Comment: What is in `rotis.map`? I can't find it searching the web. Then again, I'm flooded with dubious looking sites offering me free downloads in odd circumstances so it is hard to see if there is anything relevant or not. Also, where is that command `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts` documented? One thing to note here is that the 'fixed' pdf contains the entire font embedded. If you plan to share the document, you would need to check the licence if you used this solution. The other font is not embedded either way at all. So on my system, I see a substitution which may not be what you want either.

Comment: @cfr I added the relevant line from the map file and a quote from the pdftex manual to my question. What exactly do you mean by "fixed" PDF? Are you referring to one of the two PDFs I linked to?

Comment: It seems that, without `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=0` (the default), pdftex discards the font resource from the included object, trusting in the fact that the characters it needs are already taken care of because a font with the same name is used in the document. So you just see “M”, “F” and “1” because those are present in the document. Try with `<<pr3l8a.pfb` in the map file to force full embedding.

Comment: @egreg This is what I'm assuming too. But this can't be a universally applied "feature" without remedy, can it? It totally goes against the idea of font subsetting.

Comment: @StephanLehmke That's why `\pdfinclusioncopyfont` exists, I guess.

Comment: @egreg Well the documentation does not sound like "you must always turn this on to avoid horrible, impossible to detect errors". In the particular case, only and exactly the equals sign was missing from the diagram (because it had not been used in the document body), and this was spotted by the customer. Very awkward situation. Next, I'll try to check what turning this always on does to the file size.

Comment: @egreg Have you edited your first comment? :-) Anyways, I'd like to point out that the *default* behaviour is not to copy (which will more or less inevitably introduce errors when font subsetting is used). So every user wanting to avoid this kind of undetectable error needs to explicitly turn this switch. Furthermore, I believe full font embedding is out of the question because of licensing issues?

Comment: @StephanLehmke Yes, I did. Full font embedding is indeed “out of the question”, but the problem might depend on many factors which I'm no expert of: how does other software do in cases like this? It should scan the included object to see what characters are needed for subsetting and I don't know if this is feasible.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what this "available on disk" stuff in the doc refers to. I mean, the font (obviously) is available on disk on my system, but still the document is displayed incorrectly. What is the significance of this whole "on disc" stuff?

Comment: @egreg Uh, TBH, I'm looking for experts here ;-)

Comment: By 'fixed', I just meant the one that looked right. I didn't mean it had fixed the problem. Is the light version of the font an alternative to a medium weight? Or is it the only weight available? How is this set up in the font definition file? I'm wondering why the series change matters here but it is hard to tell with so little information about the font set up. Can you get the software producing the images to subset the fonts it embeds?

Comment: This issue has been discussed on the pdftex list [here](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2009-February/003735.html) and [here](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-pdftex/2009-April/003773.html), where you find some explanations and another workaround (removing/changing the PostScript name). Yet another solution would be something like `{\font\x=pr3l8r \pdfincludechars\x{1234567890.=hmFM}}`, which of course requires that you know which characters are used in the diagrams.

Comment: ... But I must say that the image file looks fishy to me: The `/CharSet` entry (which lists the character names of the subset) of the Rotis font only contains the letters `/A/a`, which are not even used in the diagram. If I change these to `/h/m` in the included pdf, these two letters do appear in the final pdf (without any workarounds). So you might want to check whether there is anything wrong with the "C&G-PDF-Creator V0.1".

Comment: @Robert Great hint! Just what I was looking for :-) I'll investigate further...

Comment: @Robert Your hint is exactly the answer to the question. Would you write an answer on the site please?

Comment: sure, could you re-upload the test files?